# Removing code added to htaccess with insert_with_markers

Tags: htaccess

I use insert_with_markers in a couple of my plugins to add some small bits of code to the htaccess file. What I'm unclear about is how to remove the code and markers.

For example, if I call the function like this:-

```
insert_with_markers($htaccess, "marker","RewriteBase /foobar");
```

The result in htaccess is:-

```
# BEGIN marker
RewriteBase /foobar
# END marker
```

I can use insert_with_markers, with an empty string, like so:-

```
insert_with_markers($htaccess, "marker","");
```

Which removes all the code, but the markers remain, like this:-

```
# BEGIN marker

# END marker
```

Does anybody know of a clean way to remove the markers as well?... that doesn't involve filtering the htaccess file with regex? I would like to be able to uninstall my plugins and remove all the traces if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the exact code that is inserted, then read the `htaccess` file with a function that contains `fread` command, and do a search for your inserted text, replacing the found text with an empty string. Then `fwrite` the text to the `htaccess` file.

If you are just looking for a way to remove the `# BEGIN MARKER / # END MARKER` text, then use the same process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a standard way or function to do this, but something like this I think would be a good starting point...

```
function remove_marker($contents, $marker) {
    $posa = strpos($contents, '# BEGIN '.$marker);
    $posb = strpos($contents, '# END '.$marker) + strlen('# END '.$marker);
    $newcontent = substr($contents, 0, $posa);
    $newcontent .= substr($contents, $posb, strlen($contents));
    return $newcontent;
}

$marker = 'marker';

// rewrite file using WP Filesystem
ob_start(); 
$creds = request_filesystem_credentials('', false, false, dirname($htaccess), null, true);
ob_end_clean();
if ($creds) {
    $filesystem = WP_Filesystem($creds, dirname($htaccess), true);}
    if ($filesystem) {
        global $wp_filesystem;
        $contents = $wp_filesystem->get_contents($htaccess);
        $newcontents = remove_marker($contents, $marker);
        $writeresult = $wp_filesystem->put_contents($htaccess, $newcontents, FS_CHMOD_FILE);
    }
}
```